# Compressor.js - Upload image via normal form submission (no Ajax)

Tags: javascript, image, image-compression

I'm using the following script to compress images on the client side before uploading:

https://github.com/fengyuanchen/compressorjs

I can upload the images fine via Ajax using the following code:

```
// Following is a form with #name and #image input fields and #submit button:

var formData = new FormData();

$('#image').change(function(e) {
    var img = e.target.files[0];
    new Compressor(img, {
        quality: 0.8,
        maxWidth: 1600,
        maxHeight: 1600,
        success(result) {
            formData.append('image', result, result.name);
        },
    });
});

$('#submit').click(function() {
    formData.append('name', $('#name').val());

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'form-script.php',
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    }).done(function() {

    }); 
});
```

I need to upload the image via normal form submission -no Ajax-, but I couldn't manage to do it. I am asking how to use **result** in the following code, so that the compressed image will be submitted when the form is submitted. As a side note, I use PHP server side.

```
$('#image').change(function(e) {
    var img = e.target.files[0];
    new Compressor(img, {
        quality: 0.7,
        maxWidth: 1200,
        maxHeight: 1200,
        success(result) {
            // ??
        },
    });
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After further research and trial, I was able to find how to post the compressed image without Ajax, using the following:

Form:

```
<form id="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
    <input type="file" id="image">
    <!-- A hidden input is needed to put the image data after compression. -->
    <input type="hidden" id="image-temp" name="image">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Image compression:

```
$('#image').change(function(e) {
    var img = e.target.files[0];
    new Compressor(img, {
        quality: 0.8,
        maxWidth: 1600,
        maxHeight: 1600,
        success(result) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(result);
            reader.onloadend = function() {
                var base64data = reader.result;
                $('#image-temp').val(base64data);
            }
        },
    });
});
```

Server side (PHP):

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    /* Get other form data as usual. */
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    
    if (!empty($_POST['image'])) {
        file_put_contents('images/image.jpg', file_get_contents($_POST['image']));
    }
}
```

Use what you want for directory (images/) and file name (image.jpg) as you wish.

For multiple images, use HTML/CSS classes for JS part, and a loop for PHP part.

Answer (score 0):

there is another solution too;

```
launchUpload(e) {
    const that = this;
    new Compressor(e.target.files[0], {
        quality: 0.6,
        maxWidth: 250,
        minWidth: 250,
        success(compressedResult){
            that.init(compressedResult)
        },
        error(err) {
            console.log(err.message);
        },
    })

}
 init(file) {
     this.compressed = file;
 },
```